# how to convert anyhow error to std error?

Tags: rust

I am new to anyhow and I would like to know if there is a way to convert anyhow error to std error

#### code

```rust
fn m() {
    let a: anyhow::Result<String> = Ok("".into());
    n(a);
}

fn n(r: std::result::Result<String, impl std::error::Error>) {
    println!("{:?}", r);
}
```

#### error msg

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `anyhow::Error: std::error::Error` is not satisfied
  --> src\main.rs:82:7
   |
82 |     n(a);
   |     - ^ the trait `std::error::Error` is not implemented for `anyhow::Error`
   |     |
   |     required by a bound introduced by this call
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`Deref`](https://docs.rs/anyhow/latest/anyhow/struct.Error.html#impl-Deref) or [`AsRef`](https://docs.rs/anyhow/latest/anyhow/struct.Error.html#impl-AsRef%3Cdyn%20Error%20+%20%27static%3E) impl:

```rust
match a {
    Ok(v) => n(Ok::<_, &dyn std::error::Error>(v)),
    Err(e) => n(Err::<_, &dyn std::error::Error>(e.as_ref())),
}
// Or
match a {
    Ok(v) => n(Ok::<_, &dyn std::error::Error>(v)),
    Err(e) => n(Err::<_, &dyn std::error::Error>(&*e)),
}
```

Comment: What if it's std::error::Error + Send + Sync

Comment: @lost.acfun `Deref` already supports `+ Send + Sync`, and there is an [additional `AsRef` impl](https://docs.rs/anyhow/latest/anyhow/struct.Error.html#impl-AsRef%3Cdyn%20Error%20+%20Send%20+%20Sync%20+%20%27static%3E) that supports them as well. Just change to `Ok::<_, &(dyn std::error::Error + Send + Sync)>`.